# yii get has_many relations count

Tags: php, yii

How to get the count of `childCompetency` through `childDomain` which having has many relation

```
'childDomain' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SkillRelDomain', 'skill_id'),
    'childCompetency' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SkillRelCompetency', 'domain_id'),
```

Comment: You need to share more context - right now I'm not even sure that these relations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one to many (User:Post) relationship example in Yii 1

In case of post every post belongs to a user. So relation looks like this.

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'iduser'),    
    );
}
```

Similarly, a user can have multiple posts. So relation for user as:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'posts'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'iduser'),
    );
}
```

Now when you do a `$user =  User::model()->findByPk($id)`, you can have access to relation data also

you can call

`foreach($user->posts as $post){
    echo $post->name;
}`